# Data visualization with R igraph package

Tags: r, graph, data-visualization

I'm doing a homework on data mining. Now I have a data set which stands for acquaintance network in social network. I want to visualize this network. In this network, vertex stands for user and edge stands for acquaintance relationship. Now I use igraph package for R to achieve my goal. However, my data set is too large with more than 100,000 vertexes and more than 1000,000 edges, which causes the generated graph not clear. In fact, the graph is totally unrecognized. How can I get a clear graph using igraph package? Or, which software can complete this task?

ps: my data set likes that:

```
100 20
10  2
2   4
```

each line stands for a relationship between two people

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please only use the tag [tag:data-mining] only when it's actually about data mining analysis. Your question seems to be 100% graph visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an answer on this forum, you will need to provide at least a small amount of the data that you want to analyse and many people will help you get off to a good start.

You may also want to consider using an application, such as [Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/), that is designed for the analysis of networks. It may be easier to start your visualisation and exploration of this large network.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Cytoscape, you might want to check out [Gephi](http://gephi.org/).

Another (quite different) approach to visualizing networks is by using [hive plots](http://egweb.bcgsc.ca/) -- worth checking out, too!